# Missing api level 15 image in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Yesterday I upgrade android studio to 2.0 and now I can't find api 15 image to create new emulator?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem (have API 15 installed but it won't show up in the list) and the solution was to **manually create a new AVD via the Standalone SDK Manager**

Please see my detailed post here:
[Manually create a new AVD via the Standalone SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38154130/5764320)

Answer (score 1):

My solution for **25.01.2017**

1. go to android sdk folder
2. go to tools folder

[image]

3. open old SDK Manager by double-click android.bat
4. (make sure api 15 is installed)
5. on top menu of window, click on Tools>Manage AVDs

[image]

6. create here Your device and set target.

[image]

7. open Android Studio, open window with list of devices and refresh

---

In this example, device will not have skin. You might want to use one from the list.
Memory is a bit small, maybe 2048 would be better. After creation of AVD image, list of devices in Android Studio will have opportunity to edit created device and set bigger ram.

Answer (score 0):

1. run Android SDK Manager
2. install API 15  (check android 4.0.3)

Comment: i have installed it but it does not help