# API 14 and 15 are missing in Android Studio 2.0 AVD manager

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When creating an AVD in Android Studio, system images for API 14 and 15 are missing in the list (though I actually installed the corresponding SDK versions in the SDK manager).

I think this issue appeared since the upgrade to Android Studio 2.0.

How can I create an AVD for these API versions?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*NOTE: This answer assumes that the API etc. are already correctly installed. The OP (and myself) were having the specific problem even when those prerequisites were done, but still couldn’t get the API to be available in the Virtual Device Manager when creating a new device.*

**SOLUTION**: Manually create a new AVD via the Standalone SDK Manager (steps and screenshots below).

### Mac

1. **Open SDK Manager: Tools > Android > AVD Manager**
   [image: Open SDK Manager]
2. **Launch the Standalone SDK Manager by clicking the link at the bottom**
   [image: Standalone SDK Manager]
3. **In the SDK Manager, manually create a new AVD**

   - Tools > Manage AVDs (stay on the Android Virtual Devices tab)

     - ***IMPORTANT***: I had to click away from the Android SDK Manager window and go back before the menu options would work
       [image]
   - Click **‘Create'**
     [image]
   - Click the **‘Target’** dropdown and you should see all your APIs (15 in my case)
     [image]
   - Select whatever options you want for the rest of the settings and click ‘OK’
4. Click **‘OK'** on the next confirmation window

You should then see your device with the API you wanted in the AVD Manager.
[image: AVD Manager]
[image: AVD Manager]